# SQL Rank() function excluding rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Consider I have the following table.

```
ID  value
1   100
2   200
3   200
5   250
6   1
```

I have the following query which gives the result as follows. I want to exclude the value 200 from rank function, but still that row has to be returned.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Value = 200 THEN 0
     ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY VALUE DESC)
END AS RANK,
ID,
VALUE
FROM @table

RANK   ID   VALUE
1       5   250
0       2   200
0       3   200
4       1   100
5       6   1
```

But I want the result as follows. How to achieve it?

```
RANK   ID   VALUE
1       5   250
0       2   200
0       3   200
2       1   100
3       6   1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If VAL column is not nullable, taking into account NULL is the last value in `ORDER BY .. DESC`

```
select  *, dense_rank() over (order by nullif(val,200) desc) * case val when 200 then 0 else 1 end
from myTable
order by val desc;
```

Comment: Excellent solution

Comment: Great query! Good job

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to exclude Val in Dense Rank currently ,unless you filter in where clause..that is the reason ,you get below result

```
RANK   ID   VALUE
1       5   250
0       2   200
0       3   200
4       1   100
5       6   1
```

You will need to filter once and then do a union all

```
;with cte(id,val)
as
(
select 1,   100  union all
select 2,   200 union all
select 3,   200 union all
select 5,   250 union all
select 6,   1    )
select  *, dense_rank() over (order by val desc) 
 from cte
 where val<>200
union all
 select 0,id,val from cte where val=200
```

Comment: This will not fetch the row with 200 value. But I want that row to be included.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the ranking in to separate queries for the values you want to include/exclude from the ranking and `UNION ALL` the results like so:

**Standalone executable example:**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ( [ID] INT, [value] INT );

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( [ID], [value] )
VALUES  ( 1, 100 ),
        ( 2, 200 ),
        ( 3, 200 ),
        ( 5, 250 ),
        ( 6, 1 );

SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    0 RANK ,
                    ID ,
                    value
          FROM      #temp
          WHERE     value = 200  -- set rank to 0 for value = 200
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY value DESC ) AS RANK ,
                    ID ,
                    value
          FROM      #temp
          WHERE     value != 200  -- perform ranking on records != 200
        ) t
ORDER BY value DESC ,
        t.ID

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Produces:**

```
RANK    ID  value
1       5   250
0       2   200
0       3   200
2       1   100
3       6   1
```

You can modify the ordering at the end of the statement if required, I set it to produce your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, too:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(R, 0) AS Rank ,t.id ,t.value
FROM    tbl1 AS t
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  id ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY value DESC ) AS R
                FROM    dbo.tbl1 WHERE   value <> 200
              ) AS K 
   ON t.id = K.id
ORDER BY t.value DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the original question was actually pretty close. Just adding a partition clause to the dense_rank can do the trick.

```
SELECT    CASE
               WHEN VALUE = 200 THEN 0
               ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY CASE WHEN VALUE = 200 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
                    ORDER BY VALUE DESC
               )
          END AS RANK
          ,ID
          ,VALUE
FROM      @table
ORDER BY  VALUE DESC;
```

The 'partition by' creates separate groups for the dense_rank such that the order is performed on these groups individually. This essentially means you create two ranks at the same time, one for the group without the 200 value and one for the group with only the 200 value. The latter one to be set to 0 in the 'case when'.

**Standalone executable example:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
     ID     INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
     ,VALUE INT     NULL
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
     ID
     ,VALUE
)
SELECT 1, 100
UNION SELECT 2, 200
UNION SELECT 3, 200
UNION SELECT 5, 250
UNION SELECT 6, 1;

SELECT    CASE
               WHEN VALUE = 200 THEN 0
               ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY CASE WHEN VALUE = 200 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
                    ORDER BY VALUE DESC
               )
          END AS RANK
          ,ID
          ,VALUE
FROM      @table
ORDER BY  VALUE DESC;
```

```
RANK    ID  VALUE
1   5   250
0   2   200
0   3   200
2   1   100
3   6   1
```